# xelatex option -output-directory problem with include command

Tags: xetex, include

My setup is texlive2019 + texstudio, compiler is xelatex, I setup "temp" folder for aux files in root folder same as main tex, use this command

```
xelatex.exe -output-directory=temp -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

to compiler the code to pdf. with following MWE,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nochapter]{vhistory}


\title{ \normalsize \textsc{}
    \\ [2.0cm]
    \HRule{0.5pt} \\
    \LARGE {\uppercase{\bfseries{xx}}
        \HRule{2pt} \\ [0.5cm] \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
        \normalsize  \vspace*{3\baselineskip}}
}

    %\date{}

\author{xx \\ 
    xx }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark[0]{Cover}{title}           % command in hyperref
\maketitle
%\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{toc}        % comment this line for have minitoc in each chapter
\dominitoc                              % Pre-do the minitoc
\dominilof                              % Pre-do the minilof
\dominilot                              % Pre-do the minilot
\faketableofcontents                      % hide main toc
\cleardoublepage
%\pdfbookmark[0]{Figure}{lof}          % comment this line for have minitoc in each chapter
\fakelistoffigures                        % hide main lof
\cleardoublepage
%\pdfbookmark[0]{Table}{lot}           % comment this line for have minitoc in each chapter
\fakelistoftables                        % hide main lot
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark[0]{Revision}{Revision}           % command in hyperref
\begin{versionhistory}
    \vhEntry{0.1}{20190529}{xx}{Draft}
\end{versionhistory}


\input{main/ch1/ch1}

\end{document}
```

if use

```
\input{main/ch1/ch1}
```

then the build is passed, but if i changed to

```
\include{main/ch1/ch1}
```

error will be there

```
! I can't write on file `main/ch1/ch1.aux'.
```

How could I to fix this? means let xelatex to find the right aux file? thanks.

Comment: The problem is not that it can't find it, but that it can't write it. Try if it works if you create subfolders in your temp folder. But I would simply avoid output-directory.

Comment: unrelated but `\LARGE` does not take an argument so `\LARGE {\uppercase{\bfseries{xx}}` is the same as `\LARGE {\uppercase{\bfseries{xx}}` and makes all following text large (which is why you have needed `\normalsize` to explicitly revert)

Comment: Same problem here, when using a specific output directory:  
`/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/xelatex" -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=./build %.tex`.
However, using `input{}` does not raise this error.